# Create NuGet solution-level package to copy some files

Tags: nuget, package

I have a simple task, I want to install a nuget package to a solution and have it copy files to the folder structure but I don't want to modify the solution or projects in any signifcant way.

Currently I have a solution-level package but I can't seem to get it to copy any files anywhere.  All it does currently is add a reference to .nuget\packages.config and a pointer in the solution file. This is fine, I just need it to copy files as well, the `<Files>` element doesn't seem to be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution-level packages have been deprecated as of NuGet 3 last October.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522#issuecomment-98845250